# Julia + GTK: signal to close windows

Tags: gtk, julia

I'm new using Julia + Gtk and I'm trying to create a simple window with a button that closes the window. The following code creates the window and the button, and everything seems to work fine,  but when I press the button the window does not close and the program stop responding, forcing me to kill Julia REPL. No error message appears in the REPL.

```
using Gtk

win = GtkWindow("Main", 100,50)
button = GtkButton("Exit")
push!(win,button)

showall(win)

signal_connect(button, :clicked) do widget
    println("Exit")
    Gtk.gtk_quit()
end
```

UPDATE:

The problem seems to be in the function gtk_quit() in /src/events.js:

```
function gtk_quit()
    ccall((:gtk_main_quit, libgtk), Void, ())
end
```

If I replace Gtk.gtk_quit() with ccall((:gtk_main_quit, libgtk), Void, ()) in my code I get "ERROR: UndefVarError: libgtk not defined" in the REPL .

I would appreciate if someone can suggest what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you not just looking for the `destory` function as per the [docs here](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl)?

If you replace `Gtk.gtk_quit()` with `destroy(win)` in the above code your window is closed when the button is clicked:

```
using Gtk

win = GtkWindow("Main", 100,50)
button = GtkButton("Exit")
push!(win,button)

showall(win)

signal_connect(button, :clicked) do widget
    Gtk.destroy(win)
    println("Exit")
end
```